# Solve Equation (String) with Python to every Symbol

Tags: python, sympy, equation

I have to solve a equation in python, which i get as a string input. I don't know how many symbols are in the equation or what their signature is. A typical Symbol could be "mm", "cm", "x" or something like this. The function should return some kind of array/json with the solved equation.

Little Example how it should look like:

```
solve("x/2=4")
>> ["x=8"]
>>
solve("x + 2 = y - 1")
>> ["x=y-3", "y=x+3"]
```

I tried to use SymPy-Module for this, but I didn't find a way to enter a dynamic string like above. SymPy seems to only accept "hardcoded" Symbols.

Note: String comes from a "sys.argv"-Parameter.

Comment: No, this is the way to go. In a first step, parse the input and create variables.

Comment: so i have to count the symbols and get the symbolnames in the equation? any example would be nice :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [parsing math expression in python and solving to find an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055884/parsing-math-expression-in-python-and-solving-to-find-an-answer)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. The linked question is about standard expressions and parsing, whereas this question is about finding a way to solve equations defined by a string. Nevertheless, the linked answer is a good start for parsing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SymPy can parse strings with `sympify`, but its format for equations is `Eq(x/2, 4)` instead of `x/2 = 4`. So a little preprocessing is necessary: surround the string with `Eq(` `)` and replace "=" by a comma.

```
eq = "x/2=4"
sympy_eq = sympify("Eq(" + eq.replace("=", ",") + ")")
solve(sympy_eq)   # [8]
```

and

```
eq = "x + 2 = y - 1"
sympy_eq = sympify("Eq(" + eq.replace("=", ",") + ")")
solve(sympy_eq)   # [{x: y - 3}]
```

In the latter case, SymPy picked one of the variables to solve for. To choose which one it should be, you can provide a Symbol:

```
solve(sympy_eq, Symbol('y'))   # [x + 3]
```

Or, to solve for every symbol:

```
[solve(sympy_eq, sym, dict=True) for sym in sympy_eq.free_symbols]
```

returns `[[{y: x + 3}], [{x: y - 3}]]`. The list is nested because multiple solutions could appear for each symbol. Flatten the nested list if necessary.

The options `list=True` and `dict=True` of `solve` are convenient for enforcing particular forms of output.

Comment: Thanks! FYI, if you want to get an equation back to a string (which was the original question) then you can use `str()`, like this: `str(list(solve(sympy_eq).values())[0])`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is most probably two different parts.

**Parsing:**

Parsing means turning some input into a usable output, where in your case the input is some string and the output is something, sympy can work with. A simple parsing step for example is turning strings into integers by doing `int(your_string)`. In your case, you should iterate through your string and find variables, units etc. for example by comparing with a dictionary or a list of strings. Parsing arbitrary input is quite hard, so the best idea is starting with a small set of options, e.g. search the string for occurences of typical variable names like `x`, `y` and `z` by comparing with a list `variables=['x','y','z']`.

**Computing**

Once the parsing is clean, simply plug everything into your number crunching / solvers used by sympy.

To see how such a system can work if done correctly, you can have a look at wolfram alpha. They do a quite good parsing / natural language processing and try to guess what to do from there.