# Can I ask the user to input any basic arithmetic equation without having to ask for every individual number to be computed?

Tags: python

I am a complete beginner in coding.
I want to make a simple math calculator using Python.
Instead of the traditional method of asking the user to input 2 separate integers
(in this example addition)

```
num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
total = num1 + num2
print(total)
```

I would like the user to immediately input

```
1+1
```

or any other simple math that may involve one or a combination of the following: addition, subtraction, multiplication, division.
Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [parsing math expression in python and solving to find an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055884/parsing-math-expression-in-python-and-solving-to-find-an-answer)

Comment: Woah I didn't know you could chop up information and parse it like that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you could also separate the input into a list. For example, when you input "1 + 1" there are functions in Python to separate all the characters in the list. It can make it ["1", "+", "1"]. With this, you can read each individual character and use them like input[2] to find the operation.