# Python/Pyparsing Results when Cast as Float

Tags: python, pyparsing

I found the following example from another question:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507694/pyparsing-example)

It has some pyparsing code like this:

```
from pyparsing import *

survey = '''GPS,PN1,LA52.125133215643,LN21.031048525561,EL116.898812'''

number = Word(nums+'.').setParseAction(lambda t: float(t[0]))
separator = Suppress(',')
latitude = Suppress('LA') + number
longitude = Suppress('LN') + number
elevation = Suppress('EL') + number

line = (Suppress('GPS,PN1,')
        + latitude
        + separator
        + longitude
        + separator
        + elevation)

print line.parseString(survey)
```

It says that the output is:

```
[52.125133215643, 21.031048525561, 116.898812]
```

However, I get the following output:

```
[W:(0123...), W:(0123...), W:(0123...)]
```

How can I get float outputs instead of these "W:(0123...)" values?

Thanks!

Comment: When I run this on Python 3.2 (just changing the `print` statement), I get the `[52.125...]` output. What version of Python and `pyparsing` are you using? To find the latter, do `import pyparsing` followed by `print(pyparsing.__version__)`.

Comment: @senshin: I'm using python 2.7.5 and pyparsing 1.5.7.  What version of pyparsing are you using?  I could try using pyparsing 2.0.1, but that post that I linked to was from 2011, so pyparsing was even older than 1.5.7 at that time.

Comment: I have pyparsing 2.0.1. Good point about the post being written before pyparsing 1.5.7 was out. Dunno what's going on here, sorry.

Comment: I have pyparsing 2.01 and have tried both on Py 3.3.3 and Py 2.7.6. I get the correct output. I would say you have an issue with the pyparsing install...

Comment: That's odd -- I also have Python 2.7.5 and pyparsing version 1.5.7, and am getting the correct output.

Comment: Hm...I just updated python to 2.7.6 and pyparsing to 2.0.1 and I still get the same weird behavior.  @Paul McGuire: Do you have any idea?

Comment: Try removing the parse action on number...

Comment: Ya, I can do that, but then the values are stored as strings.  Sure, I can go in myself and convert them to floats after the fact, but the point of the parseAction is to take care of that step for you.  HOWEVER...now this morning, they are being shown correctly as floats instead of W:(0123...).  I didn't change anything since upgrading my python and pyparsing...so I have no idea why it is working this morning.  Maybe the computer needed the restart after upgrading...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded my python and pyparsing version and it still did not work correctly.  However, the next morning it suddenly worked just fine.  I'm not sure why, maybe the restart overnight did something.  Either way, it appears to work correctly now.